# All delete orphan for Nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

So I have a parent object called order and a collection of child objects called orderLineItems with Cascade set to All-Delete-orphan in nHibernate. Here is my code.

```
using( var session = _sessionManager.GetSession())
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            var order = _repository.GetOrderEagerlyByOrderId(session, fromDb.Id);
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            const string user = "GNB\\Username";
            var future = now.AddYears(1);
            var taxType = new TaxType(0, "Code", "AlternateNameE", "AlternateNameF", "NameE", "NameF", "DescriptionE", "DescriptionF", 13, now, future, user, now, user, now);
            var _serviceCatRep = new ServiceCatalogueRepository();

            var serviceCatalogueItem = _serviceCatRep.GetServiceCatalogueItemByCode(session, "VR-PASS");
            var orderLineItem1 = new OrderLineItem(0, null, "DescriptionE", "DescriptionF", 1, 10, null, null, 5, false, serviceCatalogueItem, null, user, now, user, future);

            order.OrderLineItems.Clear();

            order.OrderLineItems = order.OrderLineItems == null ? new List<IOrderLineItem> { orderLineItem1 } : new List<IOrderLineItem>(order.OrderLineItems) { orderLineItem1 };

            _repository.SaveOrUpdate(session, order);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

It fails on `transaction.Commit();` with the error:

> NHibernate.HibernateException : A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance

Also, what are the differences between all and all-delete-orphan with an example.

Comment: Have you tried `cascade="all"`?

Comment: That works but I really need it to be all delete orphan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got:

```
order.OrderLineItems.Clear();

order.OrderLineItems = order.OrderLineItems == null 
    ? new List<IOrderLineItem> { orderLineItem1 } 
    : new List<IOrderLineItem>(order.OrderLineItems) { orderLineItem1 };
```

firstly if order.OrderLineItems is null then the order.OrderLineItems.Clear() will throw a NullReferenceException, secondly the problem is arising because you're assigning a new List to order.OrderLineItems so NHibernate doesn't know what to cascade the delete for.  To get it to work, just change the second line to:

```
order.OrderLineItems.Add(orderLineItem1);
```

Comment: I presumed you wanted the collection to only contain the orderLineItem1, hence to delete anything else that was there already?

Answer (score 0):

In you mapping - mark the collection as inverse()

```
HasMany(x=>x.OrderLineItems)
   .Inverse();
```

Comment: This works for cascade all and inverse = true. It also works for cascade all and inverse = false. Neither of them work for cascade all-delete-orphan